FormBuilderChoiceChip customization issues
I using package flutter_form_builder for forms and not getting how to customize these:
options: const [
        FormBuilderChipOption(value: 'Low', child: Text('Low')),
        FormBuilderChipOption(value: 'Medium', child: Text('Medium')),
        FormBuilderChipOption(value: 'High', child: Text('High')),
      ],

There is no any parameters to that like "selectedColor", "backgroundColor". As said before I would do on these customization like changing color when pressed on make different color on every chip.
Here is full code
FormBuilderChoiceChip(
      spacing: 8,
      elevation: 16,
      showCheckmark: false,
      alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
      selectedColor: Colors.greenAccent, // every chip has this color
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 220, 220, 220), //this changes color of every chip
      name: 'priority',
      ),
      options: const [
        FormBuilderChipOption(value: 'Low', child: Text('Low')),
        FormBuilderChipOption(value: 'Medium', child: Text('Medium')),
        FormBuilderChipOption(value: 'High', child: Text('High')),
      ],
  
    );

I was trying to wrap FormBuilderChipOption in Container, but getting errors due to parent widget expecting FormBuilderChipOption.
Then I was trying to make FormBuilderChipOption child as *Container *widget or Chip and it looked horrible like because FormBuilderChipOption was not expanded to parent widget and there was some kind of padding.
Any suggestions to other way how to implement more customizable Chip or answers for customizing this one are welcomed.
